# SAS: trying to get the output of this simple query

Tags: sas

im new to sas. I am trying to run this query . It has no error but its not generating the output . Please help me figure out whats wrong

```
PROC SQL;     
   CREATE TABLE work.tcrpull AS
   SELECT *
   FROM green1.super_tcr
   WHERE cleared_date between '02May2016'd and '19Jul2016'd,
     AND transaction_type NOT IN (3, 1000)
     AND commodity_Code = 'ZN'
   ORDER BY match_timestamp;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run this code

```
PROC SQL;
  SELECT *
  FROM green1.super_tcr
  WHERE cleared_date between '02May2016'd and '19Jul2016'd,
    AND transaction_type NOT IN (3, 1000)
    AND commodity_Code = 'ZN'
  ORDER BY match_timestamp;
QUIT;
```

and then choose tab View->Results to see output query results.

With using `create table` statement the output will contain only information about creation table.

Comment: do you think the comma after the between statement would be a problem ?

Comment: I think so... you should remove it.